# Share image with ShareActionProvider from Picasso

Tags: android, image, share, picasso, shareactionprovider

i spand few hours to find this solution...

so i decided to share this informatiom, maybe some one itwill helpful :)

The **first way**, shown below, takes the bitmap from the view and loads it into a file.

```
// Get access to ImageView 
ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivResult);
// Fire async request to load image
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(ivImage);
```

and then later assuming after the image has completed loading, this is how you can trigger a share:

```
// Can be triggered by a view event such as a button press
public void onShareItem(View v) {
    // Get access to bitmap image from view
    ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivResult);
    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(ivImage);
    if (bmpUri != null) {
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
    } else {
        // ...sharing failed, handle error
    }
}

// Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
       bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
       return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Make sure to add the appropriate permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming **questions**. This is not a question. If you want to answer your own question, that is fine, but please **ask a question**. The [site documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) has more about answering your own questions.

Comment: I am sorry..
i have this qeustion few hours ago and i cant find the answer on stackowerflow, so decided to fix it

Comment: My friend is using this but it shared the wrong image ID, did you have this issue? It's using a firebaserecyclerview, with Picasso

Comment: Save my time. Thanx alot

Answer (score 7):

The **second way** to share an Image does not require you to write the image into a file. This code can safely be executed on the UI thread. The approach was suggested on this webpage http://www.nurne.com/2012/07/android-how-to-attach-image-file-from.html .

```
ImageView siv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivResult);
Drawable mDrawable = siv.getDrawable();
Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
    mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
return uri;
```

You get the Drawable from the ImageView. You get the Bitmap from the Drawable. Put that bitmap into the Media image store. That gives you a path which can be used instead of a file path or URL. Note the original webpage had an additional problem with immutable bitmaps, solved by drawing the bitmap into a canvas (never shown on screen). See linked page above for details.

Comment: I'm unable to share any image with this method. I get the prompt "No app can perform this action" every single time.

Comment: even at this time, this still works. I like this solution because i do not have to worry about having to save the image to file system since it is not needed. i want to share a bitmap snapshot so saving is not required.